# How to add to a database from a list?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a column in SQLITE from a list of integers but get the following error:

```
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied."
```

Here's my code:

```
conn = sq.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(listItem VALUE)')


def data_entry():
x = 0
list1 = [61,33,4,5]
n = [l for l in list1]
while x < len(list1):
    listItem = n
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tell(listItem) VALUES (?)",
          (listItem))
    x += 1
conn.commit()


 create_table()
 data_entry()
 c.close()
 conn.close()
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop the list, not insert the entire list in one row

```
for l in list1:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tell(listItem) VALUES (?)",
      (l, ))
c.close() 
conn.commit()
```

And your CREATE TABLE statement should be creating `tell`, since `table` is a reserved word and that's what you're inserting to